# What branches of electromagnetics (or its interdisciplinary applications) do not require knowledge of electronics for research?

Tags: electromagnetism, soft-question

I am extremely interested in electromagnetics and would like to pursue research and later on some job in the field. However, I never found any appeal in electronics, especially since it was introduced to us as circuit design (Found it was too encyclopedic instead of analytic). Of course, later on I found out all about how applications of electromagnetics such as RF and Microwave Antennas, Waveguides, Radars, etc. depend on analog and digital circuits, etc. for reasonable research - and that is concerning me.

I could never, for the life of me, take circuits seriously anymore. The aversion is too great built up by 3 years of tedious and physics-less study in our university. (I had to self-learn major parts of physics of electromagnetics.)

I have tried to find alternatives, and the only road forward looks like it will be computational electromagnetics for me. Even there, I don't think there are research labs that focus solely on CEM, it being very thoroughly researched by the 2000s. Do correct me if I am wrong in saying this.

So, the question is, is there any research domain in electromagnetics or its applied interdisciplinary field (plasma physics perhaps?) that does not need me to know electronics? If the answer is no, can I join research labs as an MS student, or work somewhere in the industry doing just computational work in EM?

Comment: Maxwells equations can be studied without any significant knowledge of electronics

Comment: @jensenpaull I'm an electrical engineering student, so I'm not sure if I can be admitted to theoretical physics MS programs, especially since engineering programs here do not allow physics courses to be taken even as electives, except one 4 month course where they tried to teach all basic physics. EE MS programs, as far as I have checked, only have application based programs. Hence my question.

Comment: I would assume that any computational EM or plasma physics job  would require you to have knowledge of EM, specifically an understanding of maxwells equations

Comment: @jensenpaull I'm aware of the importance of Maxwell's equations in electromagnetics, all I was asking was about domains in EM that do not involve electronics in research or industry. You answered with Maxwell's equations, but did not specify a research domain, so I got confused, thinking you meant theoretical work. For plasma physics, do you think just an EM background is enough for MS? Of course, I would be strengthening my physics knowledge as a whole as much as possible.